# (Typescript) Calculo de diferencia en dias, horas y minutos transcurridos entre dos objetos MOMENT teniendo en cuenta una franja de horas efectivas

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

Estoy intentando elaborar una función en Typescript que me permita devolver en una cadena string formato: "0d 0h 0m", que representará el tiempo en el que se ha tardado en elaborar el trabajo de algo.

Tenemos el siguiente horario laboral efectivo:

```
Lunes a Viernes (incluidos)
De 09:00 a 17:00
```

Y las siguientes fechas:

```
var ejemplosubida = moment("20/01/2023" + " " + "09:00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var ejemploprocesado = moment("23/01/2023" + " " + "16:03:12", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
```

Tengo el siguiente fragmento de código en el que ya teniendo estos datos, si que consigo el tiempo que ha pasado entre fecha y fecha (tiempo total, no tiene en cuenta las franjas horarias efectivas):

```
pruebaEjemplos() {

moment.locale('es');
var ejemplosubida = moment("16/01/2023" + " " + "07:00:00", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");
var ejemploprocesado = moment("18/01/2023" + " " + "16:01:11", "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss");

var duration = moment.duration(ejemploprocesado.diff(ejemplosubida));
var durationDias = duration.days();
var durationHoras = duration.hours();
var durationMinutos = duration.minutes();
//6 -> sabado y 0 -> domingo
var diaSemanaSubida = ejemplosubida.day();
var diaSemanaProcesado = ejemploprocesado.day();

console.warn(durationDias + " dias");
console.warn(durationHoras + " horas");
console.warn(durationMinutos + " minutos");
console.warn("Dia semana subido: " + diaSemanaSubida);
console.warn("Dia semana procesado: " + diaSemanaProcesado);


}
```

Este ejemplo nos daría 2 dias, 9 horas y 1 minuto de tiempo total transcurrido entre un objeto MOMENT y el otro. Pero necesito que de alguna manera se tenga en cuenta el horario con los dias y horas efectivas, y así mostrar los valores reales, pero hasta aqui llego y no se como proseguir...

Comment: hay una librería plugin de moment que se llama moment-business-days probablemente sea exactamente lo que necesitas

Comment: @LPZadkiel acabo de comprobar el paquete que nombras y es bastante útil para controlar dias festivos y laborales! Pero estaría bien tener un ejemplo para ver como cuenta los tiempos entre dos fechas dadas. No veo ninguna opción donde se puedan indicar las horas del día efectivas...

Comment: Tengo problemas para importar ese paquete de NPM, el moment-business-days en Angular. El problema es que ellos te indican que para su uso debes almacenarlo en una constante con un require, como etse caso: **var momentB = require('moment-business-days');** Pero en mi caso necesito importarlo en formato **import * as momentbusiness from 'moment-business-days';** pero me da la sensación de que el paquete no lo permite o lo estoy haciendo mal. Es Angular 8 donde lo estoy metiendo.

Comment: en teoría debieses usar solo el moment-buseness-days porque este usa moment, es un wrapper, debiese funcionar `import moment from 'moment-business-days';` y luego usas moment normal y además con las funciones del business days

Comment: No necesitas Moment, ni librerías mágicas. Por un lado, Moment ya está deprecado. Por otro lado, el objeto Date de toda la vida, expone los métodos necesarios para la tarea.